# Персоналальная страница пользователя

Tags: php

Как организовать на сайте персональную ссылку на страницу пользователя, site.ru/login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, то путем GET запроса `<a href='site.ru/?name=login'>login</a>`
Если хотите изменить url то это можно сделать правилом в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ ?name=$1 [L]
```

Но тогда и ссылки сделать просто `<a href='site.ru/login'>login</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Как хочешь так и реализовывай. если site.ru/login, то тебе нужно в .htaccess 
прописать:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?__route__=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Затем в index.php смотреть на переменную `$_GET['__route__']` если она соответствует какому-нибудь пользователю в твоей БД, то и выводи страницу.

При этом нужно позаботится о зарезервированных путях, как например в vk, чтобы не было у тебя пользователя с логином messages, и просмотр личных сообщений был по урлу site.ru/messages